# Array values show in the row by row for single id using Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to show array values using PostgreSQL query like this multiple values show in
multiple row by single id.

**Table:**

```
id     name     dept.
1      name1     xxxx
1      name2     yyyy
2      name3     zzzz
4      name4     zzzz
```

Get by id response needed like this
**Table:**

```
id      name      dept.
1       name1     xxxx
        name2     yyyy
2       name3     zzzz
3       name4     zzzz
```

Comment: Why do you need everything in one row? Why don't you append rows in client side?

Comment: Because query take values very fast, client side it will take slow using more looping, if not possible query side, i will take client side option.

Comment: @MuhammedArif I'm a bit confused. Can you format your data sample properly, so tha we can see how you expect the result set to look like?

Comment: This kind of formatting is much better done on the client side when you _display_ the data in your application. The query time is not only determined by the number of rows, but also by the _size_ of the result. And simply formatting it a bit differently doesn't change the size. I doubt you will see any performance improvement if you do this (maybe even a _slower_ query as the database now only needs to "format the output" instead of just returning the query result directly)

Comment: Thanks, Ext js is using for client side.

Answer (score 0):

You want to group your data, so the place to look is in [aggregate function list] (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html), in this case it is `string_agg ( value text, delimiter text ) → text`

You want to concatenate the data from names and departments and you want the names and departments to be in separate lines as shown in the example. For that the `E'\n'` delimiter should be used:

```
SELECT
  id,
  string_agg(name, E'\n') as names,
  string_agg(dept, E'\n') as depts
FROM 
  data
GROUP BY
  id
ORDER BY
  id;
```

The answer shows you **how to** and the comments explain **why not to**. The choice is yours now.

**EDIT 1**

If you prefer preserving the number of records and displaying the ID with the firs row of the group, then you should look into window functions. Specifically [LAG](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html).

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN id IS DISTINCT FROM LAG(id) OVER(order by id) THEN id 
    ELSE null 
  END as id,
  name,
  dept
FROM 
  data
order by
  data.id;
```

The sql compares current id to the one of the previous row and outputs it or null value.

Comment: This is showing in the one column and one row like this name:[name1, name2],dept:[xxxx,yyyy], i like to get one column and multiple row for single id. if it's possible.

Comment: Please explain how you want the result to be provided? Do you want the id to be displayed on the first row of the group and not in the other rows?

Comment: Yes, ID show only first row of the group and not show other rows (based one array values).

Comment: thanks, this is fine now. I will check with my context.

Comment: How can join multiple tables show using single id.

Comment: I think this is a different question. Try looking it up in postgresql manuals or post a new question here, in stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry, your question is not very clear. I can't understand your what you are trying to accomplish. That is why creating a new question and explaining what you want, what you have tried would be a way to go. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask