# How to join multiple table (array values in row by row) using single ID?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to get array values in row by row for a join multiple table using single ID.
Here is sample,

Table 1 :emp

```
ID   dep_id  name             dept. 

1    10001   name1            xxxx  
2    10001   name2            yyyy          
3    10002   name3            zzzz
4    10003   name4            zzzz
5    10004   name5            ssss
```

Table 2: sal

```
   ID   emp_id         sal.

    1    10001        10000,
    2    10002        20000
    3    10003        30000
    4    10004        40000
```

- Need to join two tables using query, and get below response

Response:

```
ID     emp_id   name      dept.   sal.

1      10001    name1     xxxx    10000
                name2     yyyy     
2      10002    name3     zzzz    20000
3      10003    name4     zzzz    30000
4      10004    name5     ssss    40000
```

Comment: I don't see an array in your sample data. If it's just about hiding repeated values in the `ID` column, then do that when you _display_ the data. SQL isn't meant to do presentation or formatting stuff

Comment: Also, it isn't clear what the join column would be, i.e. how we know to pair the `ID = 1` records as you expect them in your output.

Comment: How is this different than your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251343/array-values-show-in-the-row-by-row-for-single-id-using-postgresql)

Comment: That's a horrible database design, but anyways. Are those columns **real** arrays (e.g. `text[]` or `numeric[]`) or is it even worse, and those are just comma separated values? And do the values in the arrays always match by position? So the first name belongs to the first salaray

Comment: only get array values in ',' ? or is it possible like my response row by row show the array values.

Comment: I am expecting Query for this response. not database design

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question.

Fun with arrays and strings!  This is an awful data model.  Value should not be stored like this -- parallel comma delimited strings *across tables*!  Sigh.

But Postgres does give you the ability to handle this.  You can split the strings on the comma, enumerate each element, and then join them together:

```
with e as (
      select e.id, u.*
      from emp_tbl e cross join lateral
           unnest(regexp_split_to_array(e.name, ','), regexp_split_to_array(e.dept, ',')) with ordinality u(name, dept, n)
     ),
     s as (
      select s.id, u.*
      from sal_tbl s cross join lateral
           unnest(regexp_split_to_array(s.sal, ',')) with ordinality u(sal, n)
     )
select *
from e join
     s
     on e.id = s.id and e.n = s.n;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cb95d3627e593704ba8a703360fe39f2) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @MuhammedArif . . . Your original question was answered.  If it is not the question you intended to ask, you should ask a *new* question.  After all, who is going to want to answer a question if all you do is change the question once it is answered?

Comment: Thanks, ok. Now i couldn't create new question in this account

Answer (score 0):

```
 with Q as
 (
     select *, 
     row_number() over (partition by dep_id order by ID ) n
     from emp
 )
 select
     case when n=1 then cast(s.ID as varchar(73)) else '' end ID,
     case when n=1 then cast(Q.dep_id as varchar(73)) else '' end emp_id,
     Q."name",
     Q."dept",
     case when n=1 then cast(s."sal" as varchar(73)) else '' end "sal."
 from Q
 inner join sal s on s.emp_id = Q.dep_id
 order by Q.ID, n;
```